# How can I show attribute in a has many relationship? - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The table columns:

[image]

Inspection Controller

```
class InspectionsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @inspections = Inspection.all
  end
```

Inspection Model

```
class Inspection < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :acordo
end
```

Acordo Model

```
class Acordo < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :inspections, dependent: :destroy
```

I want that one Acordo has many Inspections.

In Inspection index view I want to show the Acordo.created_at attribute.

How can I do that?
I tried something like that, but it didn't works

```
  <% @inspections.each do |inspection| %>
       <%= inspection.acordo.created_at %>
```

I got this error:

```
NoMethodError in Inspections#index
undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass
```

Am I missing anything?

Comment: What error did you run into? What was the actual output?

Comment: U can do that like this but u have to know Acordo id..
`Inspection.where(:acordo_id => id)` or u can use `Acordo.where(:inspection_id => inspection.id)`

Comment: @LiborZahrádka, i'm fairly sure that what he did in the html file works, because of the relationship between inspection and acordo, you can call the acordo method on inspection and that will return the acordo associated with that inspection.

Comment: that should work, that's how I do it all the time. the error must be elsewhere....you should install the gem `better errors` for rails, it will help you debug. once you install the gem restart your server and go back to the page, and let it error. you will get a box on the right that you can use to check the values of things,as you hunt down your error, and it will just be useful in general when building with rails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Your database has `inspections` with no `acordo`.

Error:

> NoMethodError in Inspections#index 
>   undefined method `created_at' for nil:NilClass

... means that `inspection.acordo == nil` (is not object) and when You want to get `created_at` it alerts that it's not proper object that can return getter of field `created_at`

I mean relation is ok but in one (or more) of Your `inspection` there is `acordo_id` but not `acordo` in table with same `id`.

Try to check if there is any `acordo` in relation:

```
  <% if !inspection.acordo.nil? %>
       <%= inspection.acordo.created_at %>
  <% end %>
```

or make some batch job (and put to scheduler) that will find malformed inspections that does not belong to any acordo and delete them or move them to table `junk_inspections` (for data consistency).

Answer (score 1):

You probably have a messed up database, did you have any entries for Inspections before adding the relationship between inspection and acordo? Check your database and check to see if you have any inspections with an empty acordo_id column. Other answers are right though, you should check the relationship inspection.acordo exists before reading an attribute on a nil object.

Answer (score 0):

Trying changing `ApplicationRecord` to `ActiveRecord::Base`, that is what I used to build my relationships. Let me know if that fixes your issue.

```
class Inspection < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :acordo
end

class Acordo < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :inspections, dependent: :destroy
```